# Select by attribute using date field values two days before machine date of ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, date

I have a date field within a file geodatabase of ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop that I am accessing using ArcMap.

An example of a value in this field: 19/11/2014 08:49:56

I want to select all rows that the date is before two days from machine date.

An example : if the machine date is 24/11, I want to select all rows before 22/11.

I need query to select rows before two days depends on machine date.

Is it possible?

Comment: Welcome to GIS@SE. You need to modify your question and Tags to indicate what software/Databases you are using and the versions so people can answer you properly.

Answer (score 1):

According to this very old document http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.3/index.cfm?TopicName=SQL_Reference the CURRENT_DATE is an object. The selection would then be

```
CURRENT_DATE - [DATE_FIELD] > 2
```

For selecting dates that are older than two days from the current date.